# Facebook SDK IOS 7 Login with APP login

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7.1, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using Facebook 3.13.0 SDK for iOS, and in IOS 8 the login with the facebook app works very well, but in IOS 7.1.2 the login with the facebook APP don't work, i have to force the login on the browser to work.

Anyone knows why this happen?

btw i'm using the FBLoginView

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]];
loginview.delegate = self;



loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 50, 50);
loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I have the same problem...